# Spring Cloud Stream - consuming interface types

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Should the new spring functional stream APIs work with interfaces? When i publish a message using a type that extends the interface MyTestEvent, the following code does not work, and i get the error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert input: GenericMessage [payload=byte[213], headers={id=a83c8f1d-bc65-ca8b-c140-521c824e47d5, contentType=application/json, gcp_pubsub_original_message=PushedAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage{projectId='tw-services-local-v2', subscriptionName='XXXXXXXX', message=data: "{"id":"9d7ab629-c699-4cf7-8d34-dfe444b35c0d","transferType":"XXXX","status":"XX","userId":"a419d940-7f17-4bf0-b071-554e46c515ca","messageId":"b7d889e0-ff4d-4949-85d5-d1f419b9ba52","eventType":"X"}"
a

```
class MyTestConsumer : Consumer<MyTestEvent> {

    val events: BlockingQueue<MyTestEvent> = ArrayBlockingQueue(10)

    override fun accept(event: MyTestEvent) {
        events.put(event)
    }
}
```

If i update the above code and replace the interface type **MyTestEvent** with the original IMPL that did the publish (MyTestEventImpl), it all works fine

Many Thanks

**Solution:**

Define an eventType - or some other common attribute on the interface/impls. Its value should be unique on every impl.

Then update the interface definition with Jackson annotations so the consumer deserialization uses the eventType value to pick the correct impl.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "eventType",
    defaultImpl = MyTestEventImpl::class
)
sealed class MyTestEvent
```

Comment: Reading https://dev.to/jakub_zalas/runtime-jackson-sub-type-discovery-in-kotlin-nid helped solve issue for me

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a more complete example on how your application is configured. Obviously there is nothing wrong with your class, so something must be in configuration which could provide some hints for us